# 検索結果のページネーションについて

Tags: python, django

djangoでページネーションをするときmethodがpostの場合、2ページ目以降に行くときのmethodがgetなため検索結果が無効になってしまいます。
どのようにすればよいでしょか?
以下が自分が書いたコードです。

```
    page = Paginator(hoge_list,10)
    params = {
        'form':form,
        'hoge_list_counter':page.get_page(num),
    }
    return render(request, 'hogehoge.html', params)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hoge_list` が検索条件のセットされたQueryだとして、Sessionなどに埋め込むのが良いかと思います。
下記のは例で、バリデーション等必要かと思いますが参考までにどうぞ。

```
def hoge_index(request):
    # Sessionから条件取得
    params = request.session.get('params')
    if not params:
        # SessionになければPOSTから取得
        params = {
            'param1': request.POST.get('param1'),
            'param2': request.POST.get('param2'),
        }

    # Sessionに保存
    request.session['params'] = params

    # ページ
    num = request.GET.get('page')

    hoge_list = HogeModel.object.filter(params)
    page = Paginator(hoge_list, 10)
    params = {
        'form': form,
        'hoge_list_counter': page.get_page(num),
    }
    return render(request, 'hogehoge.html', params)
```